# How do I test wildcard domain logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, testing

Here is an interesting problem... I have configured wildcard domains on my production site and will be using it as a customer identifier. This allows me to display the right banner/css/logos for each customer simply be pulling out the wildcard prefix (eg. CompanyABC.website.com will be displayed the logos and branding related to CompanyABC).

But how do I test this on my local Visual Studio 2010 installation? In production the site loads COMPANY.website.com etc., but locally I can only use the flat http://localhost address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file?

> 127.0.0.1  companyabc.website.local

Answer (score 0):

Put the relevant code in a separate class and create a unit test for it.

Answer (score 0):

Just get one more computer. I would prefer one more laptop. Make the IP dynamic and test it there. Results would give higher and accurate results, since your not testing different IPs on the same computer.